# EE Solspace Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform

Inherited a page. Not a EE person but learning....coming from Wordpress.
The Sign up to mailing list page using Freeform free version 4.0.12 looks lovely.  First Name, Last name email, message.... then the Sign UP button. Selecting the button does nothing. The user does not show up in the form mediation section and no notice is sent to admin.  Also, though it shows some code for a Captcha, that doesn't show up.

Yes, I can email from CP/Tools.

Something is missing.....I did spend much time reviewing other folks questions to see if I could spot the mistake....but, no success. The form is called Exclusive Sign Up   or exclusive-signup

```
{exp:freeform:form
        form_name="exclusive-signup"
        form:id="exclusive-signup-form"
        return="{segment_1}/thank_you"
        notify="me@thedomain.com"
    }
    <fieldset>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" maxlength="150" id="freeform_first_name" value="" name="first_name">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" maxlength="150" id="freeform_last_name" value="" name="last_name">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Email</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text" type="text" maxlength="150" id="freeform_email" value="" name="email">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Message</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea class="textarea" id="freeform_user_message" rows="6" cols="50" name="user_message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
            {if freeform:captcha}
            <li>
                <p>Please enter the word you see in the image below:</p>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <p>{freeform:captcha}</p>
                    <input type="text" name="captcha" style="width:140px;" />
                </div>
            <li>
            {/if}
            <li class="buttons-set">
            <button class="button" type="button"><span><span>Sign Up</span></span></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    {/exp:freeform:form}
</div>
{/exp:stash:set}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, can you paste the actual code instead of the bulleted points? You may want to try something manual like `<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">` if you aren't doing the all fields approach.

You'll also want to change notify="me@thedomain.com" to admin_notify="me@thedomain.com" (https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/freeform-4/form/#admin_notify) and add notify_admin="yes". Alternatively you could just do it all from inside of the admin.  [image]

The CAPTCHA not showing could be number of things. If you're not see'ing it while logged in as an admin go to Admin > Security and Privacy > Captcha Preferences and check toggle your settings for logged in member requirements.

Lastly, you may want to update that version of Freeform as it's several years old and numerous bug fixes have been made.  I'm also including the legacy docs link because there are some good examples of working forms at the bottom of the page. I hope some of this helps!

Freeform 4x docs - https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/freeform-4/form/

Edit: If you can, you may want to remove the stash tag pair until the issue is resolved just in case.